# YouTube responded to TubePress with an HTTP 410 - No longer available

Tags: wordpress, youtube, tubepress

Since this morning I am experiencing the following issue on my wordpress page:

YouTube responded to TubePress with an HTTP 410 - No longer available

I checked the settings, i updated the plugin - still does not work. I tried to google it - i found this error occuring among many other webpages.

Do you guys know more about it or shall I consider it only as an outage of the Youtube services? Embedded videos work just well.

Thanks for your advices / opinions.

Comment: You are using v2 of the YouTube API.  You will need to read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) and migrate your app to use the new v3 API endpoints.  What v2 endpoints were you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues more than likely:

Youtube has removed their v2 API and Tubepress has released a new version (4.1.8) that you can download here

http://community.tubepress.com/files/download/18-tubepress-free-trial/

First, delete the previous version of Tubepress, either via FTP or Wordpress. Then upload the new 4.1.8 plug-in to Wordpress via FTP, it does not appear to be available via the Wordpress menu. All you need to do is unzip and upload the folder with an FTP client to your wp-content/plugins folder. You will be able to access this the same as the previous versions of Tubepress. You will also need to generate an API (link to steps below)

Generate API Steps:

http://community.tubepress.com/topic/5633-how-to-enter-your-google-api-key-into-tubepress/

Then you will be able to use the plugin again. Unfortunately, they removed a few features for free users, but I guess that was always coming down the pipe.

Edit: Do not forget to go into installed plugins and enable the Tubepress plugin!
Edit 2: Also had to change the [tubepress] on the Wordpress page to [tubepress googleApiKey="myAPIkey"].

Answer (score 0):

The 4.1.8 Tubepress doesn't work with wordpress 4.2.2 ...

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   tubepress_app_impl_html_CssAndJsGenerationHelper::_recursivelyGetFromTheme()
>   must implement interface tubepress_app_api_theme_ThemeInterface, null
>   given, called in /homepages ...